# Does OneNote for Mac support graphics tablet input?

Tags: onenote

I was thinking of purchasing a [Wacom Bamboo Pad](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/everyday/bamboo-pad-wireless) for note taking at college. I am going to an engineering school, and often typing isn't the primary method I would like to use to enter equations, data, or text.

Does OneNote for Mac support this? I know the Windows version does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running OneNote on Mavericks here, and right now it does not support tablet input in the way you have described (I wish it did). A possible compromise is to run Windows and OneNote in a virtual machine (or BootCamp), but it really depends on your needs and what you’re willing to put up with.